# CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Pageboy' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, ios15, xcode13, swift5

I am getting the below error when I build my iOS project in Xcode 13.0 for Simulator 15 with Swift 5.5

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: i have resolved the issue by manually changing the ios target of every pod to higher level and i'm using Adjust and that have to solve the issue which is in Adjust.h replacing + (nullable id)getInstance; with + (nullable instancetype)getInstance;

Answer (score 9):

For Example:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
```

The outdated pod here seems to be `ExpoModulesCore`

and if it does not work, like it did not for me lol:

follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384358/15421728

For anyone looking for an answer.

run

```sh
cd ios
pod update ExpoModulesCore
```

and repeat the previous step for every outdated pod, if there are more outdated.

Answer (score 8):

Issue related to your's dependencies: You must have to wait for those dependencies to update to Swift 5.5, otherwise, you have to stay on Xcode 12. In my case, I updated to 13 during development.

Comment: How do you see which dependencies?

Comment: i have to build every time and check which pod is having issue than updating that one.

Answer (score 5):

I am working with react native and had a very similar error.

This worked for me:

```js
cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to downgrade XCode. I got back from 13.3 to 13.2.
You can get previous versions this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047804/7405518

Getting back to version 13.3 caused same problems again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a dependency that was using a newer version of Swift that my version of Xcode did not support.

I had a similar stacktrace

```
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'NEW_DEPENDENCY' from project 'Pods')
```

You can fix the issue by updating MacOS and Xcode

Answer (score -2):

I got this as well, but I just had to add my package again `yarn add ...` so it autolinked correctly with `react-native`