# Why is Expo iOS build failing? ...something with ExpoModulesCore

Tags: react-native, expo

Hey guys so I have an expo managed app and I want to use a notification library called Notifee which has an expo plugin. This plugin adds native code not supported by Expo Go, so I'm forced to enter bare workflow and build native iOS and Android folders.

I'm building the iOS package by running `expo run:ios`. And build fails due to something with ExpoModulesCore:

```
 The following build commands failed:
   CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 
 'Pods')
```

So I did some research and found that others had the same issue here on Stackoverflow. I tried altering the pod file and updating ExpoModulesCore
`pod update ExpoModulesCore` as this answer suggests
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104305/8561357

After updating ExpoModulesCore and re-building, I get an additional error:

```
The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Addressbook-gmgtddiltntfosevknuexadcwkpt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-BC35D93E0A296DC41D8D893483CBC12F.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

---

So why does this happen?

I saw something about Xcode version 13 not working, only 12??

Is Expo version incompatible?

Really trying to figure out what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

maybe its was to late.
if you using react native 0.64.4, add or change expo-module-core version to ^0.6.5 on your package.json.

- delete node_modules folder and yarn.lock (if you using yarn)
- reinstall node_modules using yarn `yarn install`
- sync node_modules with pod using `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` on ios folder.
- install expo modules using `npx install-expo-modules` from root project.
- then build ios using `yarn run ios`

maybe you need to see similar issue on here:
http://bataxdev.com/reactnative/unable-to-find-a-spesification-for-expomodulescore