# React Native IOS error:CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'react-native-video' from project 'Pods')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in my react native ios app (android works perfect!) I get the following two errors when I try to run the app on the simulator:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'react-native-video' from project 'Pods')
    CompileC /Users/gabriel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wooapp-ecvnzpvdhxltnxeoglpliezckkzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-image-picker.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImagePickerManager.o /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/wiii/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/ios/ImagePickerManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

I'm not using M1 chip or Rosetta.

```
"react-native": "0.68.5",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.1.0",
"react-native-video": "^6.0.0-alpha.4"
```

I'm also sometimes getting the same error but with react-native-image-picker

It's weird because these are the libraries that I added recently to my project and now they are giving me problems...

I remeber upgrading react-native from 0.64 to 0.68

```
Did you touch to some build settings as the excluded architecture?
```

Honestly, I have no idea what this is?

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details.

Are you using a Mac M1?
Are you using Rosetta?

What is your RN version?
What is your react-native-video version?

Did you upgrade React Native?
Did you touch to some build settings as the excluded architecture?

EDIT

The issue looks similar to this one: [CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Pageboy' from project 'Pods')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294922/compileswiftsources-normal-x86-64-com-apple-xcode-tools-swift-compiler-in-targe)

Check your XCode version, the Swift version of your project, the Swift version used by your version of react-native-video. You maybe have to update your dependencies

Comment: Added some more info to the OP

Comment: I edited my comment too

Comment: My xcode version is 13, hoe can I check swift version used by my react-native -video version? Sorry for noob question, but I usually build for android only, not for ios. I don't usually use xcode either, I run react-native run ios